# Why is my image so color noisy

Tags: image-quality

I just tried for hours to solve this problem maybe you can help me.
Has anyone an idea how this colored noise/grain could come to state?
We received a 3d render from our work college and then implemented it into a automatic generated pdf on our website. To be clear I don't really know how this whole process from original to pdf converted image goes but if you need to know I might search information from our developer.

[image: pdf image]
[image: original image]

Comment: Where is the image from? If a photo, do you have the exif data? What processing has it already undergone? How small a segment is that compared to the full-size original? The more detail you can give us, the better answers we can give. Right now, there's not enough to even guess.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really make the question easier to answer. "Something" happens to the image in some code unknown to us. Impossible to say what it is without seeing the code. And then it might become a coding question unsuitable for this site. Have you tried feeding the code with another version of the image? I mean another format or just resaved from Photoshop. Could be something corrupt in it to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

1. Noise is more prominent on dark images or when ISO is pushed to the extreme.
2. The big moire pattern reminds me of how some Canon sensor's look when the photo is very dark and the levels or curves are forced to compensate.

---

My assumption is that you have a poorly illuminated situation, and took a photo either very dark or with the ISO pushed to an extreme.

And additionally you upscaled the image so the noise is bigger.